# Ignore collation mismatch in MySQL globally

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

We recently ran into an issue with an illegal mix of collations, when users are searching for utf-8 characters in some application frontend. This search will try to find a search term in a list of columns. Most of the columns are uft8mb4, but one is ascii.

There is no issue when searching for only ascii characters: `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE uft8_column LIKE '%search%' OR ascii_column LIKE '%search%'`

Searching for non-ascii characters though (e.g. `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE uft8_column LIKE '%ツ%' OR ascii_column LIKE '%ツ%'`) will lead to
`1267 - Illegal mix of collations (ascii_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'`

I know how I could fix the issue in that application, but this will require a lot of code changes and future development will have to take care of it each time. And sooner or later someone will forget.

Switching the columns to utf-8 is also not an option. We need to join two affected and large tables (200k rows and 15M rows respectively) by using the ascii column in several situations. And our tests showed the query to be up to 25% faster when we use ascii instead of utf-8.

Is there any way to handle this on MySQL side globally? There is no need to transliterate values, so that the search might still find something. Instead it would be nice to have something along the lines of: If there is a collation mismatch in a condition, then this condition yields false instead of throwing an error.

Comment: Show us an example of `:search`

Comment: :search is PHP PDO syntax, should have replaced that directly. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
ascii_column LIKE '%ツ%'
```

cannot work.

`CHARACTER SET ascii` has binary codes up to hex `7F`.

The KATAKANA LETTER TU is hex `E38384`; it can be represented in utf8 (or utf8mb4)

**Constructing query**

It sounds like the user is providing a string, and your app is querying the table to locate more information.  The user does not tell you whether they are entering Japanese or English, so you check both.

Instead using `OR`, look at the data entered, then build and run *one* of these:

```
SELECT ... WHERE uft8_column LIKE '%user_input%';

SELECT ... WHERE ascii_column LIKE '%user_input%';
```

In your app, extract the first byte, convert to hex or get "ord()", and see if it is < 128.

Comment: I'm aware of that. As I wrote, I know how to fix this in code (i.e. exclude the whole ```OR ascii_column LIKE '%ツ%'``` part, if the term is non-ascii), but that needs to happen in every single snippet, which does such a query. And I would very much prefer to have some global config to make the clause return false instead of throwing an error. Otherwise new developments will always be error-prone.

Comment: @hakai - I added more.